# Gson deserialization of List<String> into realmList<RealmString>

Tags: java, android, gson, realm

I'm using retrofit with gson to deserialize my json into realm objects. This works very well for the most part. Trouble arises when dealing with

> RealmList(String(or any other basic data type))

Since Realm doesnt support RealmList where E doesnt extend Realm object, I wrapped String in a RealmObject.

```
public class RealmString extends RealmObject {
  private String val;

  public String getValue() {
    return val;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.val = value;
  }
}
```

My realm Object is as below

```
    public class RealmPerson extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String userId;
    ...
    private RealmList<RealmString> stringStuff;
    private RealmList<SimpleRealmObj> otherStuff;

    <setters and getters>
   }
```

SimpleRealmObj works fine as it only has String elements

```
    public class SimpleRealmObj extends RealmObject {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
       ...
    }
```

How can I deserialize stringStuff? I tried using a gson TypeAdapter

```
public class RealmPersonAdapter extends TypeAdapter<RealmPerson> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, RealmPerson value) throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();
        Log.e("DBG " + value.getLastName(), "");
        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public RealmPerson read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        QLRealmPerson rList = new RealmPerson();
        in.beginObject();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            Log.e("DBG " + in.nextString(), "");
        }
        in.endObject();

        return rList;
    }
```

However I still hit the IllegalStateException

> 2334-2334/com.qualcomm.qlearn.app E//PersonService.java:71﹕ main com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was NAME at line 1 column 3 path $.

I tried RealmList, RealmString adapter earlier to no avail.
The only workaround I managed to find so far is https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/620#issuecomment-66640786
Any better options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message "`Expected a string but was NAME`" can be solved by retrieving the name of the json object in the `JsonReader` before the actual json object (which is a `String` in your case).

You can take a look at the [Android documentation for JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html). It has detailed explanation and code snippet. You can also take a look at the `readMessage` method in the sample code snippet in the documentation.

I have modified your `read` method to what I think it should be. **NOTE:** I didn't test the code, so there may be some minor errors in it.

```
@Override
public RealmPerson read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    RealmPerson rList = new RealmPerson();
    in.beginObject();
    String name = "";
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        name = in.nextName();

        if (name.equals("userId")) {
            String userId = in.nextString();
            // update rList here 
        } else if (name.equals("otherStuff")) {
            // since otherStuff is a RealmList of RealmStrings,
            // your json data would be an array
            // You would need to loop through the array to retrieve 
            // the json objects
            in.beginArray();
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                // begin each object in the array
                in.beginObject();
                name = in.nextName();
                // the RealmString object has just one property called "value"
                // (according to the code snippet in your question)
                if (name.equals("val")) {
                    String val = in.nextString();
                     // update rList here 
                } else {
                    in.skipValue();
                }
                in.endObject();
            }
            in.endArray();
        } else {
            in.skipValue();
        }
    }
    in.endObject();


    return rList;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks @iRuth. This is indeed the way to deserialize the json blob and answers the original question. I will mark this as the correct answer.
For anyone else who only wish to deserialize the realmString, check my answer below.

Answer (score 33):

[It is better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17009952/504611) to use [`JsonSerializer`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html) and [`JsonDeserializer`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) rather than [`TypeAdapter`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) for your `RealmObject`, because of 2 reasons:

1. They allow you to delegate (de)serialization for your `RealmObject` to the default Gson (de)serializer, which means *you don't need to write the boilerplate yourself*.
2. There's [a weird bug in Gson 2.3.1](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=440) that might cause a `StackOverflowError` during deserialization (I tried the `TypeAdapter` approach myself and encountered this bug).

Here's how (replace `Tag` with your `RealmObject` class):

(**NOTE** that `context.serialize` and `context.deserialize` below are equivalent to `gson.toJson` and `gson.fromJson`, which means we *don't* need to parse the `Tag` class ourselves.)

Parser + serializer for `RealmList<Tag>`:

```
public class TagRealmListConverter implements JsonSerializer<RealmList<Tag>>,
        JsonDeserializer<RealmList<Tag>> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(RealmList<Tag> src, Type typeOfSrc,
                                 JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonArray ja = new JsonArray();
        for (Tag tag : src) {
            ja.add(context.serialize(tag));
        }
        return ja;
    }

    @Override
    public RealmList<Tag> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                                      JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        RealmList<Tag> tags = new RealmList<>();
        JsonArray ja = json.getAsJsonArray();
        for (JsonElement je : ja) {
            tags.add((Tag) context.deserialize(je, Tag.class));
        }
        return tags;
    }

}
```

Tag class:

```
@RealmClass
public class Tag extends RealmObject {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then register your converter class with Gson:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<RealmList<Tag>>() {}.getType(),
                new TagRealmListConverter())
        .create();
```

Comment: your solution is the best!

Comment: This solution works best and without the boilderplate code recommended in other solutions.

Comment: this still doesn't work for me: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING` in the line `tags.add((RealmString) context.deserialize(je, RealmString.class));`

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa that error means the JSON you are receiving does not match your code in some way. Is your `RealmString` class defined in exactly the same way as in @avid's original question? Also what does your JSON look like?

Comment: @VickyChijwani I posted another question, if you fancy you can help me out there, thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727315/error-deserializing-a-reallistrealmstring-into-liststring

Comment: Does this answer also assume a TypeAdapter for Tag has been registered ? Otherwise, how does GSON know how to serialize or deserialize the Tag class?

Comment: It is not solving the problem. @VickyChijwani, Can you please show your `Tag` class as well?

Comment: @EspenRiskedal no, you don't need a TypeAdapter for `Tag`. Since GSON can automatically parse simple classes containing Strings, Integers, etc, we just take care of parsing the `RealmList` and let GSON parse the `Tag` itself (using `context.deserialize`)

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal my `Tag` class is just a simple class containing built-in Java types like `String`, `Integer`, etc. Since GSON already knows how to parse such classes, we don't need to deal with it at all.

Comment: To clarify further, my `Tag` class is equivalent to the `RealmString` and `SimpleRealmObj` classes defined in the original question above.

Comment: @VickyChijwani is it possible to use same class with dynamic type for all RealmLists? smth like <RealmList<T>>

Comment: @user599807 I'm not sure but looking at it quickly, I think it should be possible.

Comment: if there is 100 data class then there will be 100 converter class? is there any better solution?

Answer (score 4):

My gson typeAdapter was the culprit.
The above error was seen as I wasnt deserializing the json into RealmPerson correctly, the first field is not a String, hence

> in.nextString()

was borking.

I looked at some example code and it hit me, I didnt have to use

> in.beginObject() and in.endObject()

to deserialize a String. The below code works.

```
public class QLRealmStringAdapter extends TypeAdapter<QLRealmString> {
@Override
public void write(JsonWriter out, QLRealmString value) throws IOException {
    Log.e("DBG " + value.getValue(), "");
    out.value(value.getValue());
}

@Override
public RealmString read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    RealmString rString = new RealmString();
    if (in.hasNext()) {
        String nextStr = in.nextString();
        System.out.println("DBG " + nextStr);
        rString.setValue(nextStr);
    }

    return rString;
}
```

}

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This was the missing link! I converted all my models to use primitive types and RealmString objects, setup an exclusions strategy like the one seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434377/robospice-with-gson-and-realm/32891674#32891674 and then implemented this RealmString TypeAdapter and everything is working perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i need a jackson serializer and deserializer for the Converting Arraylist to RealmList