# How I can use Realm to parse a large JSON and storing data

Tags: android, json, android-volley, realm

J'm really blocked into parsing and storing data using Realm,I have a large JSON and I creat all the class models like the example of RealM.

> this is my error :Caused by: org.json.JSONExcept
>   ion: Value fr at 0 of  io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not
>   map Json
>               at io.realm.Realm.createObjectFromJson(Realm.java:860)
>               at com.example.volleyapp2.ImagesActivity$ImagesFragment.loadData(ImagesActivity.java:179)
>               at com.example.volleyapp2.ImagesActivity$ImagesFragment$2.onResponse(ImagesActivity.java:133)
>               at com.example.volleyapp2.ImagesActivity$ImagesFragment$2.onResponse(ImagesActivity.java:127)
>               at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
>               at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value fr at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

my function to view data

```
 public void viewData(){

            RealmResults<ApplicationBean> im = realm.where(ApplicationBean.class).findAll();
            if(im.size()==0){Log.e("size de im = "+im.size(),"  ****");}
            else { for (int i = 0; i <im.size() ; i++) {
                Log.e("title = "+im.get(i).getId()," of pic");

            }
            }
    }
```

and this my function to parse JSON

```
public List<ApplicationBean>  loadData(JSONObject obj) throws IOException, JSONException {


            if (obj.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "objet JSON est vide ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            realm.beginTransaction();
           realm.createObjectFromJson(ApplicationBean.class, obj);
                 realm.commitTransaction();
            return  realm.allObjects(ApplicationBean.class);
        }

    }
```

and this my class model MyString :

```
 public class MyString extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String myString;

    public MyString() {
    }

    public MyString(int id, String myString) {
        this.id = id;
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }

    public void setMyString(String myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }
}
```

I used this link : https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/575
to create ReamlList to remplace List  and I can't modify my JSON

Comment: There is a mismatch between your JSON and your model class. Looks like a string (fr) that should have been an object instead. Try posting your model class and some example JSON.

Comment: `public class Parameters extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
private int account_id;
private RealmList<MyString> languages = new RealmList<MyString>();
private String url;
private String title;
private String client;
private int creation_date;
private int modification_date;
private String foreground_color;
private String background_color;`
*********
**and this a part of my JSON where I think the problem :
{"application":
{"parameters":
{"id":999,"account_id":41,"languages":["fr","en"],"url":"","title":"Le Cep","client"**
what I should do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm currently doesn't support primitive arrays. You JSON has this:

`"languages" : ["fr", "en"]`

For Realm to automatically map the JSON to your MyString class it would have to be converted to something like this:

`"languages" : [ { "str" : "fr"} , { "str" : "en" } ]`

You can also find more information about this on GitHub: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/575

Comment: Thank's Christain, but I can't edit the JSON this my class model MyString,

    **@PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String myString;

    public MyString() {
    }

    public MyString(int id, String myString) {
        this.id = id;
        this.myString = myString;
    }
getter and setter**
I creat RealmList<MyString>  like the way in your link to remplace List<String> so there's a solution or I must wait the next version of Realm ??

Comment: If you are using GSON you can create your own deserialiser. See here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733024/gson-deserialization-of-liststring-into-realmlistrealmstring