# Can you give me a hand to parse primitives using Realm?

Tags: android, json, realm

Really I like Realm but I had an issue when I try to parse my JSON, it doesn't support primitive arrays, like "Melchior" (from Realm Team) told me that :
Realm currently doesn't support primitive arrays. Your JSON has this:

```
"languages" : ["fr", "en"]
```

For Realm to automatically map the JSON to your MyString class it would have to be converted to something like this:

```
"languages" : [ { "str" : "fr"} , { "str" : "en" } ]
```

The problem is I can't change my JSON so what I supposed to do.
I thought to use something like that RealmLIst but it gives me that error : Error:(11, 8) error: Type java.util.ArrayList of field list is not supported
waiting for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my particular case, I had a similiar problem with an ArrayList. Then, in Realm documentation, I found a solution: **RealmList** .

```
public RealmList<Email> emails;
```

You can view more information on [this](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#relationships)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GSON you can write your own adapter class for mapping between a primitive array and a wrapper class. See this question here for mere details: [Gson deserialization of List<String> into realmList<RealmString>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733024/gson-deserialization-of-liststring-into-realmlistrealmstring)

Comment: Hi, Christian I don't use Gson, I migrate to Realm to avoid using Jackson and Gson, So if I'll use it there's no benefic to migrate...If you will soon fix it I can wait you. thank's Melchior