# Error deserializing a RealList<RealmString> Into List<String>

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

Due to Realm inability to work with promotive types, which include `String`s, I'm trying to implement a `JsonDeserializer` just like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733024/gson-deserialization-of-liststring-into-realmlistrealmstring).

The issue is that I'm baffled on to why I'm getting the following error:

> W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

This is part of the Json: `"tags": ["GLUTEN FREE", "NUT FREE"],`

My RealmString:

```java
public class RealmString extends RealmObject {
    private String value;

    public RealmString() {
    }

    public RealmString(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Part of the retrofited Pojo:

```java
public class Entity extends RealmObject {

    @SerializedName("tags")
    private RealmList<RealmString> tags = null;
}
```

.. and the Deserializer:

```java
public class StringRealmListConverter implements JsonDeserializer<RealmList<RealmString>> {

    @Override
    public RealmList<RealmString> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {

        RealmList<RealmString> realmStrings = new RealmList<>();
        JsonArray ja = json.getAsJsonArray();
        for (JsonElement je : ja) {
            realmStrings.add((RealmString) context.deserialize(je, RealmString.class));
        }

        return realmStrings;
    }
}
```

And I'm registering it here:

```java
public Gson provideGson() {
    return new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Food.class, new FoodDeserializer())
            .registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<RealmList<RealmString>>() {}.getType(),
                    new StringRealmListConverter())
            .create();
}
```

*edit* Here's the FoodDeserializer. It's in this mess because we had to use Composition over Inheritance in order to please the Realm gods:

```java
public class FoodDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Food> {
    public static final String TAG = FoodDeserializer.class.getSimpleName();

    Gson mHelperGson;

    public FoodDeserializer() {
        mHelperGson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    }

    @Override
    public Food deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        String type = json.getAsJsonObject().get("responseType").getAsString();
        switch (type) {
            case "Platter":
                return parsePlatter(json);
            case "FoodItem":
                return parseFoodItem(json);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    private PlatterEntity parsePlatter(JsonElement json) {

        FoodEntity food = mHelperGson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<FoodEntity>() {
        }.getType());

        ArrayList<FoodItemEntity> items = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonElement je1 = json.getAsJsonObject().get("items");
        if (je1 != null) {
            JsonArray list = je1.getAsJsonArray();
            if (list != null) {
                items = mHelperGson.fromJson(list.toString(), new TypeToken<List<FoodItemEntity>>() {
                }.getType());
            }
        }

        return new PlatterEntity(food, items);
    }

    private FoodItemEntity parseFoodItem(JsonElement json) {

        FoodEntity food = mHelperGson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<FoodEntity>() {
        }.getType());

        Boolean readyToEat = null;
        JsonElement je1 = json.getAsJsonObject().get("readyToEat");
        if (je1 != null) {
            readyToEat = je1.getAsBoolean();
        }

        String heatingInstructions = null;
        JsonElement je2 = json.getAsJsonObject().get("heatingInstructions");
        if (je2 != null) {
            heatingInstructions = je2.getAsString();
        }

        ArrayList<IngredientEntity> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonElement je3 = json.getAsJsonObject().get("ingredients");
        if (je3 != null) {
            JsonArray list = je3.getAsJsonArray();
            if (list != null) {
                ingredients = mHelperGson.fromJson(list.toString(), new TypeToken<List<IngredientEntity>>() {
                }.getType());
            }
        }

        NutritionEntity foodNutritions = mHelperGson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<NutritionEntity>() {
        }.getType());

        return new FoodItemEntity(food, readyToEat, heatingInstructions, ingredients, foodNutritions);
    }
}
```

I would like to use a `JsonDeserializer` over `TypeAdapter`, but any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `realmStrings.add((RealmString) context.deserialize(je, RealmString.class));` why? ... you can use `realmStrings.add(new RealmString(je.getAsString()));`

Comment: or use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493101/gson-deserialization-for-realm-list-of-primitives (remeber to change int to string)

Comment: You can't deserialize Realm list in GSON, if you don't override your own deserializer.

Comment: @Selvin I've used that answer as a base for this, and still doesn't work.

Comment: @Alexander I've updated my answer, I think the problem is the RealmString is inside the Food object, which is why it's not trigerring my RealmString deserializer!

Comment: You're right. Could you post the code for your FoodDeserializer as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my feelings were right. I had to add the `StringRealmListConverter` to the `FoodDeserializable` constructor, like this:

```java
    public FoodDeserializer() {
        mHelperGson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<RealmList<RealmString>>() {
                    }.getType(),
                    new StringRealmListConverter())
            .create();
    }
```

Comment: There's actually a much easier way to do this - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JsonDeserializationContext` (passed as the second parameter to your `deserialize` function) to deserialize the `RealmString` correctly. The `context` knows how to deserialize all your custom types that are registered with the current Gson instance. See the documentation for `JsonDeserializationContext` here: https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializationContext.html.

The reason it doesn't work with your current code is because you're creating a *new* Gson instance in `FoodDeserializer` which doesn't know about the custom deserializer for `RealmString`.