# RoboSpice with Gson and Realm

Tags: android, gson, robospice

I'm using [RoboSpice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) with GsonSpringAndroidSpiceService. I also want to add [Realm](https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/) to save the data.

the problem is that in realm each object has to extend realmObject, but the gson in the roboSpice trying to parse the realmObject instead of ignore it.

I've tried to add exclusion stategy:

> ```
> Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
>         .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
>
>             @Override
>             public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
>                 return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
>                 return false;
>             }
>         })
>         .create();
> ```

then

> ```
>     GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter(gson);
> ```

also tried (separately) to add @expose to the fields in the object, and

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

in the two ways I have the same error:

> 09-07 11:21:04.615    8443-8443/com.mm.rsApp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
>   09-07 11:21:04.620    8443-8443/com.mm.rsApp D//SpiceManager.java:1018﹕ 11:21:04.625 main Bound to service : GsonSpiceService
>   09-07 11:21:04.625    8443-8466/com.mm.rsApp D//SpiceManager.java:1133﹕ 11:21:04.628 Thread-16362 Bound ok.
>   09-07 11:21:04.690    8443-8443/com.mm.rsApp I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41b8f088 time:525639153
>   09-07 11:21:21.890    8443-8466/com.mm.rsApp D//SpiceManager.java:245﹕ 11:21:21.896 Thread-16362 Sending request to service : CachedSpiceRequest
>   09-07 11:21:21.895    8443-8466/com.mm.rsApp D//RequestProcessor.java:70﹕ 11:21:21.898 Thread-16362 Adding request to queue 1103121632: CachedSpiceRequest [requestCacheKey=login, cacheDuration=-1, spiceRequest=com.mm.rsApp.requests.BaseRequest@41d700c0] size is 0
>   09-07 11:21:21.900    8443-8466/com.mm.rsApp D//RequestProcessor.java:89﹕ 11:21:21.902 Thread-16362 Adding entry for type class com.mm.rsApp.model.LoginResult and cacheKey login.
>   09-07 11:21:21.900    8443-8466/com.mm.rsApp D//RequestProgressManager.java:54﹕ 11:21:21.904 Thread-16362 Request was found when adding request listeners to existing requests.
>   09-07 11:21:21.900    8443-8466/com.mm.rsApp D//RequestProgressManager.java:64﹕ 11:21:21.905 Thread-16362 Sending progress PENDING
>   09-07 11:21:21.905    8443-8609/com.mm.rsApp D//RequestRunner.java:68﹕ 11:21:21.908 Thread-16369 Processing request : CachedSpiceRequest [requestCacheKey=login, cacheDuration=-1, spiceRequest=com.mm.rsApp.requests.BaseRequest@41d700c0]
>   09-07 11:21:21.905    8443-8609/com.mm.rsApp D//RequestRunner.java:114﹕ 11:21:21.910 Thread-16369 Cache content not available or expired or disabled
>   09-07 11:21:21.910    8443-8609/com.mm.rsApp D//RequestRunner.java:128﹕ 11:21:21.913 Thread-16369 Calling netwok request.
>   09-07 11:21:21.910    8443-8609/com.mm.rsApp D//RequestProgressManager.java:64﹕ 11:21:21.914 Thread-16369 Sending progress LOADING_FROM_NETWORK
>   09-07 11:21:21.915    8443-8443/com.mm.rsApp V//DefaultRequestProgressReporter.java:110﹕ 11:21:21.917 main Notifying 1 listeners of progress com.octo.android.robospice.request.listener.RequestProgress@41d71138
>   09-07 11:21:21.915    8443-8443/com.mm.rsApp V//DefaultRequestProgressReporter.java:110﹕ 11:21:21.921 main Notifying 1 listeners of progress com.octo.android.robospice.request.listener.RequestProgress@41d83c50
>   09-07 11:21:27.255    8443-8609/com.mm.rsApp D//RequestRunner.java:131﹕ 11:21:27.257 Thread-16369 Network request call ended.
>   09-07 11:21:27.255    8443-8609/com.mm.rsApp D//RequestRunner.java:151﹕ 11:21:27.259 Thread-16369 Start caching content...
>   09-07 11:21:27.260    8443-8609/com.mm.rsApp D//RequestProgressManager.java:64﹕ 11:21:27.262 Thread-16369 Sending progress WRITING_TO_CACHE
>   09-07 11:21:27.260    8443-8443/com.mm.rsApp V//DefaultRequestProgressReporter.java:110﹕ 11:21:27.265 main Notifying 1 listeners of progress com.octo.android.robospice.request.listener.RequestProgress@41e12c08
>   09-07 11:21:27.440    8443-8609/com.mm.rsApp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=18: stack overflow on call to Lcom/google/gson/internal/$Gson$Types;.resolve:LLLL
>   09-07 11:21:27.440    8443-8609/com.mm.rsApp I/dalvikvm﹕ method requires 96+20+12=128 bytes, fp is 0x5deea348 (72 left)
>   09-07 11:21:27.440    8443-8609/com.mm.rsApp I/dalvikvm﹕ expanding stack end (0x5deea300 to 0x5deea000)
>   09-07 11:21:27.440    8443-8609/com.mm.rsApp I/dalvikvm﹕ Shrank stack (to 0x5deea300, curFrame is 0x5deeac94)
>   09-07 11:21:27.480    8443-8609/com.mm.rsApp D//RequestRunner.java:199﹕ 11:21:27.482 Thread-16369 An unexpected error occurred when processsing request CachedSpiceRequest [requestCacheKey=login, cacheDuration=-1, spiceRequest=com.mm.rsApp.requests.BaseRequest@41d700c0]
>       **java.lang.StackOverflowError
>               at** com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:356)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:141)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:83)
>               at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:359)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:122)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:46)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:92)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:91)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:142)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:83)
>               at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:359)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:122)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:46)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:92)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:91)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:142)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:83)
>               at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:359)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:122)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:46)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:92)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:91)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:142)
>               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:83)
>               at com.google.gson.Gson.getAda

**please help me with any idea why I get this error and how can I solve it**

Comment: Realm users have already had a similar issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/696. I can see a GSON configuration tutorial link in the comments thread.

Answer (score 5):

I used `Robospice` with `Retrofit` and `Realm`.

I solved it by overriding `createConverter()` in my `Service` class that extends `RetrofitGsonSpiceService`. Unfortunately, I can't say more clearer because I haven't used `GsonSpringAndroidSpiceService`.

So in my `Service` class it looked like this:

```
@Override
protected Converter createConverter() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .create();

    return new GsonConverter(gson);
}
```

So the idea is to find where `Gson` can be initialized with default configuration. And that's why I passed the above mentioned configuration to `Retrofit` also.

```
new RestAdapter.Builder()
               .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
               .build();
```

Hope it helps.