# RealmList of String Type in Android

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I'm using Realm for Local storage in Android. I'm getting following response form server.

```
[{
    "ListId": 10,
    "Names": ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"]
}]
```

Here is my Model

```
   public class Model extends RealmObject {

    private int ListId;
    private RealmList<String> Names = new RealmList<String>()

    public int getListId() {
        return ListId;
    }

    public void setListId(int listId) {
        ListId = listId;
    }

    public RealmList<String> getNames() {
        return Names;
    }

    public void setNames(RealmList<String> names) {
        Names = names;
    }

}
```

And I'm getting this for ArrayList

Type parameter 'java.lang.String' is not within its bound; should extend 'io.realm.RealmObject'.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gson deserialization of List<String> into realmList<RealmString>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733024/gson-deserialization-of-liststring-into-realmlistrealmstring)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Realm version 4.0.0 will add support for RealmList that can contain String, byte[], Boolean, Long, Integer, Short, Byte, Double, Float and Date values.

Please refer to this pull request:

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/5031

And the realm changelog:

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Is is possible to extract list of Strings back?

Comment: Adding this is creating error : Warning:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (3.0.2) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61406606/2898715, if you want to migrate your `RealmList`s of `String`-wrapping `RealmObject`s to `RealmList<String>`

Answer (score 14):

RealmLists doesn't support simple strings yet. so you have to wrap each String into its own object:

You can see a work-around here: [Gson deserialization of List<String> into realmList<RealmString>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733024/gson-deserialization-of-liststring-into-realmlistrealmstring?rq=1)

or here:
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#primitive-lists

Comment: instead of just copy/pasting links, a good explanation would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

yes it is limitation from realm, you can't create array or list of strings, Please refer to the following link

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/575