# How to handle List<String> in Realm?

Tags: java, android, gson, realm

I have tried add the JSON response into the Realm database. I handled the response through GSON and then tried to convert to realm. I have already extended RealmObject for my response model class. I am also using RealmString class for handling List by using RealmList. But when I tried to GSON to Realm object I get errors. I am looking for an example of this kind if anyone has one. All support are appreciated. Below is my JSON response.

```
{
    "transactionType": 12,
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            77.7,
            12.9
        ]
    },
    "rooms": {
        "bedrooms": {
            "total": 2,
            "metadata": [
                {
                    "name": "bedroom 2",
                    "images": [
                        "Eshant",
                        "Abhijeet"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what had you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gson deserialization of List<String> into realmList<RealmString>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733024/gson-deserialization-of-liststring-into-realmlistrealmstring)

Comment: Thnx EpicPandaForce....

Comment: And One more question how make a Primitive Type List in Realm. i add the data in a list but if i log these value its show with key how to mange this can u help me for this also because realm new for me and no such information about realm. thanks in advance. @EpicPandaForce

Comment: its show RealmList data like this {"location":{"coordinates":[{"value":12.23}]} , but i want this {"location":{"coordinates":[12.23]} how to mange this

Comment: Only Lists of RealmObjects are supported. List of Primitives is not supported. So a wrapper class is required, just like for Strings. Yeah I know, they should really fix that.

Comment: So how can i resolve this problem for the time. because string is also show a key and value.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a very similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993141/1666063

Here is short walkthrough how to to JSON -> GSON -> Realm:

1. Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate a POJO with getters and setters for GSON
2. for the classes and subclasses you want to store in Realm add `extends RealmObject` to them
3. for all your classes that `extends RealmObject` make sure to put `@PrimaryKey` on of the fields (like an ID)
4. replace any usage of `List<Foo>` with `RealmList<Foo>`
5. Foo MUST `extends RealmObject` as well (even if it is a String)
6. Add a `TypeAdapter` to GSON that can handle `RealmList`([here is one](https://github.com/Turistforeningen/SjekkUT/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/no/dnt/sjekkut/gson/RealmListConverter.java) I wrote that takes a generic T)