# Conditional field visibility for Spring MVC Rest Resource

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

Well first i would like to mention about the architecture a little bit.

We have a UI application that uses a REST api for all the operations and use cases. UI application uses credentials to call REST api, since there are other non-UI application consuming same services.

We do authentication and authorization on REST api application using Spring Security. In fact whole application uses Spring portfolio from top to bottom.

For authentication and authorization of operations on UI application we also use Spring Security. We protect urls and display the currently logged in user only the operations that he is authorized to do.

Here is the new requirement: Some logged in users see a resource with restrictions. That mean same resource is shown with fewer fields or fewer updatable fields.

Exploring around, we narrowed down to two methods:

- Use different representation for each restricted access. Based on some HTTP header set and known by client.
- Use different resources for each restricted access.

If the resource-representation combinations are too much, different resource object may be less maintainable. An automated HTTP-header based restrictor aspect can be implemented. Also client have provide some header and this add minor complexity to the client.

If combinations are not too much, a new resource is created for each restricted access. Client have to call the right one at the right time. This approach can reveal hidden domain concepts as new resources and design may look more clean.

What are your thoughts? Which approach would you take?

Answer (score 0):

From your architecture, I am guessing that you have the security filters setup already (I believe it's called OncePerRequestFilter in Spring?). The way I have approached this in the past is use my security filters to get the "Role" of the client (assuming you can have roles assigned for each client which map to specific permissions/restrictions on each resource object). Now based on the "Role" I have custom JSON serializer/deserializer strategies (I used GSON for this inclusion/exclusion type adapters. You can read more [here (Gson custom seralizer for one variable (of many) in an object using TypeAdapter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271375/gson-custom-seralizer-for-one-variable-of-many-in-an-object-using-typeadapter) ) that will take care of what resource fields should/should not be populated/serialized. This way, you will continue to use the same resource object and TypeAdapter for each resource object which will determine the serialization/deserialization of the resource object based on the role of the client.

One more idea that comes to my mind is method interceptors (Spring AOP). Although I have never tried it with method interceptors, I think it should still work in the sense that you will intercept the method right BEFORE it returns (and after the business logic is done) and look at the role of the client making the request. Based on that role, you can determine what fields to null out (most serializers (atleast gson) do not serialize null fields) and not serialize, before converting it to json (or whatever your return type might be) and sending it over to the client

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, i tried that with Spring AOP interceptors. I even created a seperate library that contains interceptor and common annotation library to mark fields as restricted for some roles. 
What i am not certains is, from the rest api point of view, authentication and authorization is based on other apps, (my UI app or another system) but from my UI app point of view, security is based on user and roles retrieved from api on login (Users, Managers, Super Users etc.). 
Is it right to introduce security concepts of UI to the REST api in some HTTP header way?

Comment: A very good question and my personal opinion would be that it depends on the implementation. The way I handled it before was EACH CLIENT has a role or some kind of identifier as to what is their origin. For example, your UI APP client can have a role of "TRUSTED_CLIENT" which means that there will be further authorization needed based on the "role" of whosoever is trying to access your api THROUGH that UI APP client (based on their login, as you mentioned, they can be super users, managers, users etc.)

Comment: The other systems (other clients), you can have a "TRUSTED_THIRD_PARTY_CLIENT" role which means that you will look at the "scope" to which this client has access to, rather than going one step deeper as to what granular role does the user have who is trying to make this api call through this third party client. My point being, it seems that you will need 2 levels of authorization based on what kind of client is making the call. And this will have to be handled at your security filter layer itself.

Comment: in very simple words, if(TRUSTED_CLIENT), DO ROLE CHECK, ELSE IF(TRUSTED_THIRD_PARTY_CLIENT), DO SCOPE CHECK, ELSE RETURN 401.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed description. Another aspects that effect the decision is : Restful idempotence and caching, readability of this infrastructure and maybe my TRUSTED_THIRD_PARTY_CLIENT is a mobile app and that is also need to display info in a restricted way according to logged in user in that app. What do you think about deciding whether to use multiple resource or http header approach with these factors and resource-role combination factor i mentioned above?

Comment: You could use the same concept as well ..
if(Trusted_client) do only role check, else if(trust_third_party_client) do scope check and do role check (if necessary based on your business logic), else return 401. I don't know what you mean by HTTP HEADER approach. You will still need the "Authorization" HTTP HEADER in order get the access_token/clientId (whatever you decided as a part of your implementation) from the client and determine their role (and possibly the role of the user who has logged in).

Comment: In standard situations i give a username and pass to the UI app or another System. (eg.superuiapp - superpass, anotherXSystem - xpass). I thinks that credentials are not of external users. So Authorization header is used for this credentials. For header approach i mean, i want to store the external user's identity, along with the rest api client's identity i mentioned above. Maybe a header named X-User with a token or the id of the external user could be used. I also don't want to diverge to very custom impl., since i will be recommending the chosen approach to variety of systems and projects.