# StackExchange API handling with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, api, retrofit

I am in the process of writing a neat Android application to interact with the API, that follows the Google Android user experience.

The application will be using Retrofit (to make REST-api mechanisms easier).

Now, I have created Java classes that corresponds to each API call.

For example, `Site.java` class that handles the `/sites` API in this fashion:

This is condensed for brevity:

```
public class Site{
    @SerializedName("api_site_parameter") String mApiSiteParameter = "";
    // snip
}
```

The interface is wired up in this fashion, called `ISites.java`

```
public interface ISites{
    @GET("/sites")
    public void getAllSites(@Query("filter") String filterName, 
                            Callback<List<Site>> cbAllSites);
}
```

The big question is, since the common wrapper is used, how can I make Retrofit return back a `List<Site>` collection regardless, this could equally apply to other objects such as `Question`, `Answer` and so on.

After testing with Postman extension under Chrome, I observed the following, which is a stumbling block, the common wrapper is returned in the response, regardless of which REST-api to use, however, the `items` field within the JSON output, contains the array of `Site` in this case.

I deduced, that there's a field in the common wrapper that is not returned, called `type` *The idea here is to cheat a little bit later on...* and, since it's not part of the filter, which meant having to create a new filter via `/filter/create` API and apply that as part of invocation to the Retrofit's `RestAdapter` call, as in:

```
RestAdapter ra = new RestAdapter.Builder()
   .setServer("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1")
   .setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL)
   .build();
ISites sites = ra.create(ISites.class);
sites.getAllSites("my_commonwrapper_filter", Callback<Site>(){
   @Override
   public void failure(RetrofitError argRetrofitError){
   }
   @Override
   public void success(List<Site> sites, Response response){
   }
});
```

After studying the Gson's custom `TypeAdapterFactory` which was [answered here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271375/gson-custom-seralizer-for-one-variable-of-many-in-an-object-using-typeadapter), am I missing something here, this is what I have so far.

Created a class called `SEWrapper.java` which went like this:

```
public class SEWrapper{
    @SerializedName("items") List<Class ?> mListItems;
    @SerializedName("type") String mJsonObjType;
}
```

Changed around the Site.java source to use `SEWrapper` instead of `Site`, and modified the REST call.

This code which is adapted from the question on StackOverflow,

```
private class SEWrapperTypeAdapterFactory extends CustomizedTypeAdapterFactory<SEWrapper> {
    private SEWrapperTypeAdapterFactory() { super(SEWrapper.class); }
    @Override
    protected void beforeWrite(SEWrapper source, JsonElement toSerialize) {
       // Ignored for now as all this is Read Only operation!
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterRead(JsonElement deserialized) {
       String typeOfJsonObj = deserialized.getAsJsonObject().get("type").getAsString();
       if (typeOfJsonObj.equalsIgnoreCase("site")){
          JsonArray jSiteArray = deserialized.getAsJsonObject().get("items").getAsJsonArray();
          // Convert that to List<Site> type which I cannot figure out
       }
   }
```

Am out of ideas on how to get around this stumbling block.

I could, in theory, rewrite it to return a Retrofit's `Response` object and manually parse each JSON object along with creating a List of that type `Site`, it does feel cumbersome and long-winded for each of the API object returned.

Am I doing this the wrong way or have I set my expectations a little bit too high with the Retrofit library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question was very simple when a lightbulb moment went off.

I realized that the list of items can refer to any object depending on the API call to the *stackexchange.com* site, so it meant a *type of* class that shall be used when the JSON's `items` get deserialized.

The solution was rather simple.

*CommonSEWrapper.java*:

```
public class CommonSEWrapper<T>{
   // snip
   @SerializedName("items") List<T> mListItems;
   // snip
}
```

Then to apply for the `Site` object, the interface for the Site's REST API would end up like this, *ISites.java*:

```
public interface ISites{
   @GET("/sites")
    public void getAllSites(@Query("filter") String filterName, 
                            Callback<CommonSEWrapper<Site>> cbAllSites);
}
```

and finally the execution of the REST via Retrofit would look like this:

```
RestAdapter ra = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setServer("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1")
        .build();
ISites sites = ra.create(ISites.class);
ra.getAllSites("", new Callback<CommonSEWrapper<Site>>(){
   @Override
   public void failure(RetrofitError argRetrofitError){
   }
   @Override
   public void success(CommonSEWrapper<Site> sites, Response response){
       // sites is filled in, just like magic!
   }
});
```

Clean, elegant and simple, and no messing around with the innards of Retrofit's magic.

Hope this will help others who found themselves in a similar predicament that I experienced.

Enjoy.

Comment: Question : every time for getting retrofit response we have to create CommonSEWrapper.java classes according to our response ? is this good way, or we can use http://stackoverflow.com/a/26555618/2382964 this answer to parse JSON one-by-one .