# Is there a way to ignore JsonSyntaxException in Gson

Tags: json, gson

I have a json that looks like this:

```
[
{
_id: "54b8f62fa08c286b08449b8f",
loc: [
   36.860983,
   31.0567
]
},
{
_id: "54b8f6aea08c286b08449b93",
loc: {
coordinates: [ ]
}
}
]
```

As you can see, loc object is sometimes is a json object, sometimes is a double array. Without writing a custom deserializer, is there a way to avoid `JsonSyntaxException` and set the loc object to null when it is a json object rather than a double array.

Comment: Well, I don't think so Devrim Bey :) I've already managed this by using a custom deserializer; set object to null when I catch the exception (Maybe TypeAdapter is better approach). I'm looking for something a little bit easier like `new GsonBuilder().ignoreExceptions().create()` or something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any easy way (I mean a property/method call at Gson) for *custom seralization/deserialization of a specific field* at a json value.

You can see source code of [com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java?r=1114), and debug on its inner class `Adapter`'s `read` method. (That's where your `JsonSyntaxException` occurs)

You can read [Custom serialization for JUST specific fields](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-gson/FuGn-Hnt96I) and track its links. It may be implemented at future release of Gson. (Not available at latest release 2.2.4)

I would write some code for this. Maybe that's not what you are looking for but it may help somebody else.)

**Solution 1** (This has less code compared with the second solution but second solution's performance is much more better):

```
public class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    private double[] loc;
}

public class BaseClass {
    @SerializedName("_id")
    private String id;
}

public class CustomTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<BaseClass> {
    private Gson gson;
    public CustomTypeAdapter() {
        this.gson = new Gson();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, BaseClass value)
            throws IOException {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented for this question!");
    }

    @Override
    public BaseClass read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        BaseClass instance;
        try {
            instance = gson.fromJson(in, SubClass.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            instance = gson.fromJson(in, BaseClass.class);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
private void test() {
    String json = "[{_id:\"54b8f62fa08c286b08449b8f\",loc:[36.860983,31.0567]},{_id:\"54b8f6aea08c286b08449b93\",loc:{coordinates:[]}}]";

    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<BaseClass>>(){}.getType();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(BaseClass.class, new CustomTypeAdapter()).create();
    List<BaseClass> list = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);

    for(BaseClass item : list) {
        if(item instanceof SubClass) {
            System.out.println("item has loc value");
            SubClass subClassInstance = (SubClass)item;
        } else {
            System.out.println("item has no loc value");
            BaseClass baseClassInstance = item;
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2** (It is one of the Gson Developers suggestion. [See original post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271375/gson-custom-seralizer-for-one-variable-of-many-in-an-object-using-typeadapter)):

Copy below class to your project. It is going to be a base class for your custom [TypeAdapterFactory](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html)s.

```
public abstract class CustomizedTypeAdapterFactory<C>
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    private final Class<C> customizedClass;

    public CustomizedTypeAdapterFactory(Class<C> customizedClass) {
        this.customizedClass = customizedClass;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // we use a runtime check to guarantee that 'C' and 'T' are equal
    public final <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        return type.getRawType() == customizedClass
                ? (TypeAdapter<T>) customizeMyClassAdapter(gson, (TypeToken<C>) type)
                : null;
    }

    private TypeAdapter<C> customizeMyClassAdapter(Gson gson, TypeToken<C> type) {
        final TypeAdapter<C> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);
        return new TypeAdapter<C>() {
            @Override public void write(JsonWriter out, C value) throws IOException {
                JsonElement tree = delegate.toJsonTree(value);
                beforeWrite(value, tree);
                elementAdapter.write(out, tree);
            }
            @Override public C read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                JsonElement tree = elementAdapter.read(in);
                afterRead(tree);
                return delegate.fromJsonTree(tree);
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Override this to muck with {@code toSerialize} before it is written to
     * the outgoing JSON stream.
     */
    protected void beforeWrite(C source, JsonElement toSerialize) {
    }

    /**
     * Override this to muck with {@code deserialized} before it parsed into
     * the application type.
     */
    protected void afterRead(JsonElement deserialized) {
    }
}
```

Write your POJO and your custom CustomizedTypeAdapterFactory. Override `afterRead` method and handle double array as you asked at your question:

```
public class MyClass {
    @SerializedName("_id")
    private String id;
    private double[] loc;
    // getters/setters
}

private class MyClassTypeAdapterFactory extends CustomizedTypeAdapterFactory<MyClass> {
    private MyClassTypeAdapterFactory() {
        super(MyClass.class);
    }

    @Override protected void afterRead(JsonElement deserialized) {
        try {
            JsonArray jsonArray = deserialized.getAsJsonObject().get("loc").getAsJsonArray();

            System.out.println("loc is not a double array, its ignored!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            deserialized.getAsJsonObject().remove("loc");
        }
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
private void test() {
    String json = "[{_id:\"54b8f62fa08c286b08449b8f\",loc:[36.860983,31.0567]},{_id:\"54b8f6aea08c286b08449b93\",loc:{coordinates:[]}}]";

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new MyClassTypeAdapterFactory())
            .create();

    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>(){}.getType();
    List<MyClass> list = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);

    for(MyClass item : list) {
        if(item.getLoc() != null) {
            System.out.println("item has loc value");
        } else {
            System.out.println("item has no loc value");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the accepted answer since it is the best way to achieve my goal. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did this. It is shorter, but I think **@DevrimTuncer**s answer is the best one.

```
//This is just Double array to use as location object
public class Location extends ArrayList<Double> {
    public Double getLatidute() {
        if (this.size() > 0) {
            return this.get(0);
        } else {
            return (double) 0;
        }
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        if (this.size() > 1) {
            return this.get(1);
        } else {
            return (double) 0;
        }
    }

    public static class LocationDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Location> {
        @Override
        public Location deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            try {
                JsonArray array = json.getAsJsonArray();
                Location location = new Location();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                    location.add(array.get(i).getAsDouble());
                }

                return location;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```