# In Dropwizard how to compare Date in json

Tags: java, json, assert, dropwizard

I am trying to write a test case for the REST API part of my website. I use dropwizard.

```
@Test
public void getAll(){
    assertThat(resources.client().target("/blogcomments").request().get(List.class))
            .isEqualTo(GsonInstance.INSTANCE.getGson().toJson(list));
    verify(dao).getAll(list);
}
```

And what I get is like this :

`[{"comment"="comment", "date"=1464906153750L, "id"=1, "name"="name", "url"="url"}]`

In the `assert` above, if I use an object to compare, actually I am using `[api.BlogComment@e3e181ab]`.

If I use Gson to convert object to json like this:

```
@Test
public void getAll(){
    assertThat(resources.client().target("/blogcomments").request().get(List.class))
            .isEqualTo(GsonInstance.INSTANCE.getGson().toJson(list));
    verify(dao).getAll(POJOs.BlogCommentPOJO.toString());
}
```

What I got is:

`org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :"[{"id":1,"url":"url","comment":"comment","date":"Jun 2, 2016 6:27:50 PM","name":"name"}]"
Actual   :[{"comment"="comment", "date"=1464906470531L, "id"=1, "name"="name", "url"="url"}]`

How to deal with the Date format? How to compare whether two JSON are equal?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you seem to be trying to compare `String` representations of *actuals* and *expected* values. I would suggest you override `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods of your POJO and it's inner classes. Then compare the objects in your test cases by simply using `assertEquals`. (Also override `toString` for debuggability)

However, for some reason if you need compare `String` representations, you may do as below: (I wouldn't recommend it, though)

- write custom serialiser/deserialiser. If you are using Gson, take a look at this: [Gson custom seralizer for one variable (of many) in an object using TypeAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271375/gson-custom-seralizer-for-one-variable-of-many-in-an-object-using-typeadapter)
- Dropwizard uses Jackson by default. So, alternatively, you can fetch the same `ObjectMapper` that Dropwizard uses in your test cases and use it to serialiser. It *must* match the serialisation.

Comment: Thank you so much! Truly the reason is different strategy of Gson and dropwizard. ObjectMapper.readValue works

Comment: @SmartFingers If you found the answer helpful, I suggest you "accept" it.