# GSON : Custom serialization for String

Tags: android, serialization, gson

```
public class Data{
     public String str;  //String (that may contain line breaks) I need to serialize as it is.
}
```

**Why I needed custom Serializer for string?**
Without custom serializer it serializes this as object `{"str":{"count": 292,"hashCode": 0} }`

I need it to be `{"str":"..............."}`

How to do it with custom Serializer?

There are example of custom serializer for custom types, but could not find anything that helps to serialize String type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public class DataSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Data> {


        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(Data data, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {

            JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
            object.addProperty("src",  data.src);

            return object;
        }
 }
```

Add this to Gson Like this

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
.registerTypeAdapter(Data.class, new DataSerializer())
.create();
```

Comment: What if Model class has more fields, it will also need to manage by DataSerializer class right?

Comment: What may be the reason field String str being treated as Object, instead String?

Comment: field String str  treated as JSON because it's value is in JSON format

Comment: Yes it may be valid Json format string, but it is string type of data on model. Is there any way to treat it as string with annotation or just simple without writing DataSerializer  for entire Data class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11272452/8166037 check out this answer. It could help your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Gson supports strings out of box and you don't have to implement any string serializer and vice versa yourself. What I guess might happen to your case is merely importing a wrong string class, say `import foo.bar.baz.String;` or less obvious `import foo.bar.baz.*`, or you just have a `String` class implementation right in the package where your `Data` class is declared in. (This cannot explain what values were really assigned to `str`, though, -- it would never work in Java causing `ClassCastException`). A wrong class might be indicated with numeric `count` and `hashCode` without any `char[]`-declared fields, so I don't believe this is a `java.lang.String` in your case. Also, a more hypothetical thing here might be use of reflection that discarded the string type adapter out of your `Gson` instance, no matter how and how weird it sounds. In any case, you don't have to implement even a single line to serialize Java strings with Gson.

Regarding the accepted answer: it is suboptimal. If, for whatever reason, there is nothing wrong with your imports, your package does not declare a custom `String` class, and your `Gson` instances do not suffer from reflection surgery, but Gson still serializes such strings as nested objects (have no ideas why then), you'd only need a single special `String` type adapter without any need of creating type adapters for any class that uses that weird `String` as a field:

```java
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(/*real.package.here.*/String.class, (JsonSerializer</*real.package.here.*/String>) (s, type, context) -> new JsonPrimitive(s.toString())) // whatever the real Java string is obtained
    .create();
```