# GSON: Same object referenced in two classes, duplicated instance after decode

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm using GSON for persist and recover data into my app. The problem is that, in come cases, I have objects that are referenced in two different objects, I mean, the same instance is referenced. So multiple paths can lead to the same object.

When persisting the decoded GSON string of my model, In case of existing two references for the same object in two places, it persist them apparently correct, but when opening the app again and load the data and decoding the GSON string, two different instances of the same object are being created instead of being the same instance. Doing a change in the first instance doesn't reflects in the second instance, because are different objects after decoding the json.

This is a trace of the problem:

Having Model, Person and Car:

```
public class Model{
    Car car;
    Person person;
}

public class Person{
    Car car;
}
```

I set the same instance of car to model and person:

```
Car car = new Car();
model.setCar(car);
person.setCar(car);
```

car is the same instance in car and person, and now I encode and persist the data with GSON:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(model);
```

Then I close the app and reopen the app, and I decode the json String to recover the model:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(json, Model.class);
```

Now, I have two different instances of Car, one inside person and other inside Model, they are not the same instance but must be the same instance! If I modify the car of Model then the car of person is not modified, that's an error.

How to solve this?

Comment: Kindly, upload related code so other can help for problem

Comment: @PJain I added even more code to clarify it

Comment: Do your model classes: `Car`, `Person` are implement `equals` method or/and have some `identifier` which identifies them? Without this it would be hard to identify whether we should create new object or use already parsed.

Comment: @MichałZiober they have name, and other values. How can I tell GSON that the instances must be the same?

Answer (score 2):

`Gson` by default does not provide any way to cache instances and check whether it was already seen or not. To do that we need to implement custom `com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory`. Also, we need to assume that `Car` class (and `Person` class if needed) implements properly `public boolean equals(Object o)` and `public int hashCode()` so we can use `Map` to cache all instances.

Let's assume that your model looks like below:

```
class Model {
    private Car car;
    private Person person;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Car car;

    // getters, setters, toString

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Person person = (Person) o;
        return id == person.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}

class Car {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // getters, setters, toString

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Car car = (Car) o;
        return id == car.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

`Car` and `Person` classes have `id` fields which we use to distinguish instances. You can use any properties you want in your implementation.

Custom adapter implementation which uses `Map` to cache instances:

```
class CachedInstancesTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private final Map<Class, Map> cachedMaps = new HashMap<>();

    public CachedInstancesTypeAdapterFactory(Set<Class> customizedClasses) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(customizedClasses);
        customizedClasses.forEach(clazz -> cachedMaps.compute(clazz, (c, m) -> new HashMap<>()));
    }

    public final <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        if (cachedMaps.containsKey(type.getRawType())) {
            final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
            return createCustomTypeAdapter(delegate);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T> TypeAdapter<T> createCustomTypeAdapter(TypeAdapter<T> delegate) {
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                Object deserialized = delegate.read(in);

                Map tInstances = Objects.requireNonNull(cachedMaps.get(deserialized.getClass()));
                return (T) tInstances.computeIfAbsent(deserialized, k -> deserialized);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And below you find example how to use it:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = createGson();

        String json = gson.toJson(createModel());
        System.out.println(json);

        Model result = gson.fromJson(json, Model.class);

        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("Two car instances are the same: " + (result.getCar() == result.getPerson().getCar()));
    }

    private static Model createModel() {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setId(9943);
        car.setName("Honda");

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(123);
        person.setName("Jon");
        person.setCar(car);

        Model model = new Model();
        model.setCar(car);
        model.setPerson(person);
        return model;
    }

    private static Gson createGson() {
        Set<Class> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(Car.class);
        classes.add(Person.class);

        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new CachedInstancesTypeAdapterFactory(classes))
                .create();
    }
}
```

Above code prints, firstly `JSON`:

```
{
  "car": {
    "id": 9943,
    "name": "Honda"
  },
  "person": {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Jon",
    "car": {
      "id": 9943,
      "name": "Honda"
    }
  }
}
```

And after that:

```
Model{car=Car{id=9943, name='Honda'}, person=Person{id=123, name='Jon', car=Car{id=9943, name='Honda'}}}
Two car instances are the same: true
```

### Note

Above `CachedInstancesTypeAdapterFactory` implementation is not thread safety. Moreover, you must create always new `Gson` object for each thread and for each attempt when you want to deserialise `JSON` payload with `Car` and `Person` instances. Reason is `CachedInstancesTypeAdapterFactory#cachedMaps` object can be used only once.

See also:

- [Gson custom seralizer for one variable (of many) in an object using TypeAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271375/gson-custom-seralizer-for-one-variable-of-many-in-an-object-using-typeadapter)

Comment: incredible answer, thank you very much, tomorrow I will try to use this and I will accept your answer, you are a very good contributor!