# Is there an easy way to make Gson skip a field if there's an error deserializing it?

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize some data with Gson (Java) and the API I'm pulling data from sometimes has data of the wrong type in a field. I.e. if I'm expecting an array of `String` types, it might encounter a `Boolean`.

Now I realize these are my current options:

- Always ignore the field from deserialization
- Create a custom `TypeAdapter` to do the deserialization and the catch the error and do something (like set the field to `null`)

However I'm asking if there's another way to easily make it so if there's an exception parsing a certain field, that Gson will just ignore that field.  Something like an annotation on that field like `@Skippable` or maybe a setting when using the `GsonBuilder` to create a `Gson` object?

Is anyone familiar with such a thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not an easy task to handle properly all possible errors in `JSON` and mismatches between payload and `POJO` model. But we can try to implement `com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory` interface and wrap all default `TypeAdapter`s in `try-catch` and skip invalid data. Example solution could look like this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new IgnoreFailureTypeAdapterFactory())
                .create();

        Entity entries = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), Entity.class);
        System.out.println(entries);
    }

}

class IgnoreFailureTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public final <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        return createCustomTypeAdapter(delegate);
    }

    private <T> TypeAdapter<T> createCustomTypeAdapter(TypeAdapter<T> delegate) {
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                try {
                    return delegate.read(in);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    in.skipValue();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

class Entity {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

For example, above code prints:

```
Entity{id=null, name='1'}
```

for below `JSON` payload:

```
{
  "id": [
    {
      "a": "A"
    }
  ],
  "name": 1
}
```

See also:

- [Same object referenced in two classes, duplicated instance after decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58841054/gson-same-object-referenced-in-two-classes-duplicated-instance-after-decode)