# Use Gson RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory with lenient = true setting

Tags: java, json, polymorphism, gson, deserialization

The API we ingest returns some malformed JSON (in particular `Double.NaN` is serialized to a `String` with "NaN").
To allow this gson always sets `lenient` to true and correctly serializes this back to `Double.NaN`.

Now, we wanted to use the `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` class from **gson-extras** to remove some boilerplate code. 
The just described behaviour does not apply here anymore, we get the message

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: JSON forbids NaN and infinities: NaN

which
should have been ignored because of the `lenient` option normally set from gson.

**Consider this small example:**

```
class Base
{
   String type;
   double malformedField;
}

class A extends Base{}
class B extends Base{}
```

We use the `type` field in order to determine which subclass we want, because of course otherwise we couldn't infer the correct type.

**This is the setup we use to create our subclasses and deserialize:**

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Base> adapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(Base.class, "type", true)
    .registerSubtype(A.class, "A")
    .registerSubtype(B.class, "B");

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(adapterFactory)
    //.setLenient() // Has no effect at all
    .create();

String json = "{\"type\":\"A\", \"malformedField\": \"NaN\"}";
Base a = gson.fromJson(json, Base.class); // throws said Exception
```

**Implementation in `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`:**

Upon checking the code from the `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` I noticed that the `lenient` option is never set to true, because we invoke the `fromJsonTree` method of `com.google.gson.TypeAdapter`, in which we create a new `JsonTreeReader` without a possiblity to change the `lenient` option.

```
public final T fromJsonTree(JsonElement jsonTree) {
    try {
        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonTreeReader(jsonTree);
        return read(jsonReader);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new JsonIOException(e);
    }
}
```

I tried to manually set this through debugging to `true` and that seemed to work as expected (no 
`NumberFormatException` and object gets deserialized correctly with specified type).

Now the question is: Is there something I am missing about why we can't use the `lenient` option here? At a first glance this seems to be a bug from **gson-extras** but I am unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite a bug from `gson-extras` since `com.google.gson.TypeAdapter` class comes from core library. I would suggest to register one more `TypeAdapterFactory` and force `lenient` for all `JsonReader` instances:

```
class AlwaysLenientTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public final <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        return createCustomTypeAdapter(delegate);
    }

    private <T> TypeAdapter<T> createCustomTypeAdapter(TypeAdapter<T> delegate) {
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                in.setLenient(true);
                return delegate.read(in);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(adapterFactory)
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new AlwaysLenientTypeAdapterFactory())
        .create();
```

See also:

- [Is there an easy way to make Gson skip a field if there's an error
  deserializing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59655279/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-gson-skip-a-field-if-theres-an-error-deserializing)